# Codeigniter Radio button form validation?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to validate three radio button inputs using codeigniter form validation rule:

### HTML Page

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('register')" ?> method="POST">

    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="BMW">
    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Ferrari">
    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Jaguar">

    <input type="submit" name="submitter">

</form>
```

### Controller

```
public function register()
{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        i know what to do here
    }
    else
    {
        i know what to do here
    }
}
```

How to do form validation in codeigniter for radio button in my case ?

Comment: Do you want to confirm that a choice has been made? Or something else?

Comment: Yes sir... in my case, i left all the radio buttons unchecked... but, if a user click submit button without choosing any of these radio buttons i want to display error using codeigniter form validation...

Answer (score 0):

Load library for form validation and other helpers in application/config/autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation');

$autoload['helper'] = array('form', 'url');
```

In your controller

```
public function register()

{

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required');

     if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

In your view file use below code for printing validation errors

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show form error use `form_error()` function and to show all error use `<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>`

## HTML PAGE

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('register'); ?>" method="POST">
    <?php echo form_error('cars'); ?>
    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="BMW">
    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Ferrari">
    <input type="radio" name="cars" value="Jaguar">

    <input type="submit" name="submitter">

</form>
```

## Controller

```
public function register(){

    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        echo "i know what to do here"; //die;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "i know what to do here"; //die;
    }
    $this->load->view('welcome_message'); // your html view page
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `in_list` validation as an addition to `required` that has been mentioned by the others.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cars', 'Cars', 'required|in_list[BMW,Ferrari,Jaguar]');
```

Also, as a self-reminder, since it took me 1 year to know about this.